# Cant get image from resources

Tags: vb.net

My resource1 contains graphic files named dot1, dot2 , dot3 etc. and each represent image of dice wall.
My game class have method updateView()

```
Public Sub updateView()
    Dim imageName As String

    image = "dot" & ToString(dice1.getDots())
    Form1.PictureBox1.Image = CType(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(imageName ), Image)

    image = "dot" & ToString(dice2.getDots())
    Form1.PictureBox2.Image = CType(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(imageName ), Image)

    ... etc.
End Sub
```

I want to update 5 pictureboxes on form1 with images from reasource box depending on rolled number. This code isnt working and i dont know why.

ps. sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're trying to `GetObject(imageName)`, where `imageName` is declared as an empty string. You can solve this two ways, either define `imageName`, or search for the string you create in the `image` variable:

```
Dim imageName As String

imageName = "dot" & ToString(dice1.getDots())
Form1.PictureBox1.Image = CType(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(imageName ), Image)
```

or,

```
image = "dot" & ToString(dice1.getDots())
Form1.PictureBox1.Image = CType(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(image), Image)
```

In either case, using [Option Strict](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311329) would help to solve problems like these.